# What is being said in this scene from Looper?

Tags: translation

I'm a user over at another Stack site, for Movies & TV. Someone posted a question there about the film *[Looper](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Looper_%28film%29)* and a Chinese broadcast that is played for a few seconds during the film. We may be film buffs, but we've certainly been proven to be hopelessly unknowledgeable about about the Chinese language.

I'm hoping some of you good folks would be able to lend a hand with this and offer a translation. I'm aware this *challenges* the "what's on-topic" a little, as I haven't shown an attempt, but I'm hoping my reasons will allow it. The scene in question [can be found here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Jyf5TTLBpMc&t=2m10s) (it starts at right place):

There's a few lines of dialogue on the television about *The Rainmaker*, but that's all I can understand.

Comment: Barely audible on my computer even with max volume. Mandarin with heavy southern accent. Seems to be talking about an explosion.. Someone must have better ears than I.

Answer (score 1):

The dialog says: `"随着神秘的Rainmaker在中西部的暴乱事件中继续他的帮派战争, ..."`

My translation is : "As the mysterious Rainmaker continues his gang war in the Midwest, ..."

Comment: Have you even seen the movie? The rainmaker is a gang leader and a bloody killer who use super power to rip people into pieces.

Comment: It sounds more like 爆震. On the screen, we can see 打破, which I guess is translated from "breaking". So, it seems that the news in the TV is poorly constructed.

Comment: The 暴乱 sounds like 犯罪 to me. If that's the case, the 帮派 could be something like _fān wèi_, though I can't find any valid word around it. Anyway, the newscaster's accent is too thick but the tone is consistent.